# Box seals: Two arrows instead of 4-digit manufacturing code, is this a fake?

Tags: building

I have bought a lego architecture 21001 "John hancock" from a website.But as the title, there is no 4-digit code on the sticker. Could you guys help check if the stick is not the original one?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to Brickset this [set](https://brickset.com/sets/21001-1/John-Hancock-Center)'s shelf life was:

```
LAUNCH/EXIT01 Jul 2008 - 31 Dec 2011
```

I have 42000 set from 2013 (and some others too) which still use stickers with arrows like one of your pictures. So it wasn't until few years later currently used stickers (with production week marked) have been introduced.

Comment: Hi Alex, many thanks for the clarification. it's a great relief for me!